Actor who played deposition lawyer on The West Wing
Depositions seem to happen at least once per season on The West Wing and the lawyer conducting the deposition is almost always the same character. This clip is an example. What's the name of the actor who played this character? I've looked up and down and I can't seem to find his name.

The character is Larry Claypool, played by John Diehl. The clip is from the episode "Lord John Marbury", a transcription can be found here:

CUT TO: INT. DEPOSITION ROOM - DAY 
Claypool is seated opposite Josh
  and Sam, continuing the deposition. There are several other people in
  the room.
CLAYPOOL And you didn't make a single note?
JOSH No.
CLAYPOOL You're asking me to believe...

The wikia page lists the cast:

Guest Starring

John Diehl as Larry Claypool


